# Разрешение jQuery внутри React компонента

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Как React компоненту позволить запустить jQuery код из файла main.js?

Есть такой код в файле main.js

```
$('.category-menu > li').hover(function(e) {
  $(this).addClass('active')
  e.preventDefault()
})
$('.category-menu').mouseleave(function(e) {
  $('.category-menu li').removeClass('active')
  e.preventDefault()
})
```

ему нужно работать в компоненте, но место этого ничего. Кто сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: А что Вам мешает сделать это в самом компоненте? без jQ, или прям нужно jQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если main.js - это сборка (webpack, gulp и т.д.) то

```
npm install jquery --save
```

В стартовом файле сборки:

```
let $ = require('jquery');
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
```

из компонентов реакта вызывается как обычно, но надо учесть, что на момент вызова jQuery с селекторами некоторые элементы могут быть просто не отрисованы, поэтому селекторы ничего не находят. Все зависит от конкретного случая. Но лучше конечно не смешивать, иначе можно получить непредсказуемые эффекты

Если main.js - это просто скрипт, содержащий вызовы jQuery, то добавьте на вашу страницу загрузку jQuery из локального каталога или с CDN перед подключением скрипта main.js

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

или (если есть jquery на локальном сервере)

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: WebPack вообще нет у меня. main.js это обычный файл где jQuery код. Запуск слайдера, выпадающее меню и т.д. 
а если не смещивать, то какой выход еще есть?

Comment: Тогда просто в html добавьте загрузку jquery локально или с cdn

Comment: так и есть, и все же не работает((

Comment: Если убрать код из Component React и разместить на index.html все работает в противном случае нет(

Comment: тогда дополните вопрос кодом реакта, где осуществляется вызов

Comment: Спасибо Дмитрий, сделал в файле $(document).on(...) помогло